# Vintage DC generator

Tags: dc, generator

[image] this is a DC Continental Electrical C0. Model D16  generator that came with the Fairbanks Morse hit and miss motor I restored. It was used to generate electricity for a farm house. I can not find any info on Internet for this generator. I would like to clean and restore it for use. My question is how was this supposed to power a farmhouse? I would like to run something for show. The spec label " Type D16, volts 9.12, kw .120, rpm 1350, winding CPD, amps 12,cont duty.

---

Comment: I guess you will have to rotate it somehow.

Comment: So, a compound wound 9-12V generator for about 120W (e.g. 10V at its rated 12A). If you need to power a house using it now, use LED lights!

Comment: Engine looks nice!  If no info on the web perhaps find an antique engine forum.  (This was my first hit.) https://www.smokstak.com/forum/

Comment: [Here's the company that made your generator.](http://www.cecoinc.com/) They changed name, but claim to have files on every thing they ever built back to the founding of the company in 1921.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question really is.  The specs seem quite clear.

> volts 9.12, kw .120, rpm 1350, winding CPD, amps 12,cont duty

This means that if you rotate it at 1350 RPM (22.5 Hz), it can put out 9.12 V at 12 A.  The claimed power output is 120 W, although from the voltage and current we get (9.12 V)(12 A) = 109 W.  Close enough, I guess.  The "cont duty" part means *continuous duty*, which tells you that it can supply the 9.12 V and 12 A for long periods of time.  In other words, these are not short term peak ratings.

The spindle at right looks like it was meant to be driven by a belt.

120 W is not much to run a farm house on.  This probably just meant a few lights.  Nowadays you could get much more light using efficient LEDs.  This thing could nicely light a typical farm house using modern parts.